# App Inventor - Having trouble with list index (I think)

Tags: app-inventor

This script (when i type test in plain text and key in key) returns me with the (custom) error message "Key Letter not found" and "Letter not found" meaning the index lists return 0 here is my code  [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjkmC.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFAe1.png) [Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77GxE.png) [Image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs4hu.png) [Image5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHCs3.png) [Image6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWI4e.png) (I can't embed images)

Comment: DRY - Don't repeat yourself... see an example here how to avoid redundancy https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/WZa7t4o11i0/FVSJPpkK07wJ

Comment: Take a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKbem.png) I made. If you have a list named alphabet with A, B, C, etc. you just need to get the item number and it will return the letter. That reduces your encrypt function to two blocks and the list (not shown). You can re-use  the alphabet list for all of your other functions too. That will make your code much easier to work with. I think the problem you are having is with the first block. Can you please list what the values of all the variables are, because we can't tell from here.

Comment: You can also use the Do-It command if you are connected to the AI companion by right-clicking the block. That will tell you what values you have for each variable.

Comment: @JohnLocke these pictures give me the error Runtime Error
The operation index in list cannot accept the arguments: , [(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)], [*empty-string*]
Note: You will not see another error reported for 5 seconds.
https://ibb.co/nFFiRp
https://ibb.co/gDDysU encrypt is what you told me to do

Comment: You do not need such long blocks testing for every possible character. As I showed in my screenshot, you can reduce it down to just a few blocks. That will significantly reduce your chance of an error by simplifying the code. My suggestion is to export your code as an aia and post it here so that it's easier to see than screenshots.

Comment: @JohnLocke its not the thing in the background is making sure there arent any numbers im showing whats at the bottom is what i changed

Comment: Here is the room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182163/conversation-for-john-locke-and-the-lava-weilder

Comment: See above in case you missed the notification ^^

Comment: @The_Lava_Wielder I started a [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182163/conversation-for-john-locke-and-the-lava-weilder) if you want to discuss the problem there. I am keeping it unfrozen, but I am not going to be able to do so forever.

Comment: Make a new chat room? I linked the .aia file so you could take a look and try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this- don't divide by 27. There are 26 letters in the alphabet, so change the modulo to 26. If your key and plaintext are both A, you will get 1+1 plus another 1, which will give you C. Increasing the number in the mod function to account for the possibility of the mod being 0 will not help because dividing will change a number differently- like dividing 8 by 2 is not the same as 8-2.

If the above paragraph doesn't make any sense, that's ok. What you have to do is add the key and plaintext, then subtract 1. Then do your mod function with 26. Then you can add one.

Comment: gives me the same error message
```The operation index in list cannot accept the arguments: , [(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)], [*empty-string*]
Note: You will not see another error reported for 5 seconds.```

Comment: https://nofile.io/f/YgshXS4TqhS/CodeMakerBreaker.aia is the link to my app

Comment: Hey, I sent you the link to my .aia file if you could take a look at it sometime.

Comment: @The_Lava_Weilder Sorry, I just haven't gotten around to it yet. I'll try to look at it today.

Comment: @The_Lava_Wielder In your preencrypt function, you use the split at block, but the value you give is an empty string. Is the purpose of that to make each character its own item in a list? I think the problem is also with the blocks immediately below them. What is the purpose of preencrypt?

Comment: The 2 blocks right below where you set LS and KS are switched. Your select item should be where the alphabet variable block is, because alphabet is a list, and the result of select will be a character.

Comment: I split every time because as far as I know there is no way to focus on one char in a string so I do that instead but I think I am missing something here.  I tried switching the list and thing and now when I click encrypt nothing happens

Comment: @The_Lava_Weilder If you want one character in particular, you can use [segment text](segment) and set the length to 1. Then set the start to whatever character you want. If you want the first, it's 1, the second is 2, etc. It doesn't do anything because the first item returned by segment text is an empty string.